# Should we make a canonical "How to send data using serial?" question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

I have noticed that there are a lot of questions that are like "How can I make my Arduino send data to my R program?" "How can I make my Arduino send data to my C++ program?" "How can I make my Arduino send data to my Processing program?" "How can I make my Arduino send data to my Matlab program?"

Because the Arduino part of the question is almost always the same (How can I make my Arduino send data to a computer), should we make a canonical "How to send data using serial?" question, and close others as off-topic?

Comment: I think we could really benefit from a one-stop list of how to interface with Arduino's serial output in a variety of languages.

Comment: Related: http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/can-we-get-some-canonical-questions-going