# Can we get some canonical questions going?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

For those who don't know what a canonical question is, view **[this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)**.

Anyway, can we brainstorm some ideas for ones? I feel like they could be a great addition to our community.

**[This question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1233/should-we-make-a-canonical-how-to-send-data-using-serial-question)** already talks about a canonical question for sending data via serial

However, what other topics could we do? Does anyone want to write one? I feel like we need someone to get the ball rolling and then we can let others edit it (as a community wiki).

The nice part about this is one person could start it and then others can help build it. As it grows, we can start closing duplicates that are covered in the canonical question. In addition, chat can be used to distribute the work between people by collaborating effectively.

Some topics ideas:

- Uploading errors
- Web servers (how to control [] with an Arduino [])
- ...whatever else you can think of.

To do this, ask a fairly broad question (that, of course, can't be closed as *too broad*), answer it yourself, and (optional) flag for a moderator to make the question CW.

Comment: I'm envisioning this post to serve as a sandbox for canonical posts (and later turn into a list of example questions for examples).

Comment: Can [link](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/153/how-to-check-my-arduino-board-is-working-or-dead) be one of them?

Answer (score 1):

I have been contacted a few times on how to use a custom/downloaded/user-space Arduino library in the Arduino IDE such that it can be used with:

```
#include <library.h>
```

One single question that describes the process, linked to from the [library](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library), would prove helpful to some people.

Answer (score 1):

Serial communications with an additional 101 on the basics of serial communications. to reduce the need to have the base line problems asked repeatedly like not crossing TX and RX lines or no common earth.